# Javascript if/else not working. Odin project's Rock, paper, scissors

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I’ve been trying to solve the Rock, Paper and Scissors project but I can’t figure out how to make the if/else statement. I did it a lot of times and finally I think I’m near to solve the issue, but the thing is, every time I run the program I get the wrong output.

For example, I used ‘Paper’ and the computer used ‘Rock’, but the console showed that ‘It’s a tie’, but in the code I wrote that if player chose paper and computer chose rock the message should have been ‘You win. Paper beats Rock’. The same happens when I choose ‘Paper’ and the computer chooses ‘Scissors’.

I used toLowerCase() method but after many changes, even when remove it and write exactly the words in the if/else this does not appear to be the problem.

What do I need to correct? Thank you so much!!!

This is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Rock Paper Scissors!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    //Computer's selection



    function computerPlay() {


      let selectRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
      if (selectRandom === 0) {
        return 'Rock';
      } else if (selectRandom === 1) {
        return 'Paper';
      } else {
        return 'Scissors';
      }


    }


    console.log('Computer chose: ' + computerPlay());


    //Play round between humand and computer

    function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {

      //Change to lowercase
      let player = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
      let computer = computerSelection.toLowerCase();


      //If player chooses rock
      if (player === 'rock') {
        if (computer === 'rock') {
          return 'It\'s a tie. Try again'
        } else if (computer === 'paper') {
          return 'You loose. Paper beats Rock'
        } else {
          return 'You win. Rock beats scissors'
        }

      }
      //If player chooses paper
      else if (player === 'paper') {
        if (computer === 'paper') {
          return 'It\'s a tie. Try again'
        }
        if (computer === 'scissors') {
          return 'You loose. Scissors beats Paper'
        } else {
          return 'You win. Paper beats Rock'
        }
      }

      //If player chooses scissors
      else {
        if (computer === 'scissors') {
          return 'It\'s a tie. Try again'
        } else if (computer === 'rock') {
          return 'You loose. Rock beats Scissors'
        } else {
          return 'You win. Scissors beats Paper'
        }
      }

    }

    const playerSelection = 'Paper';
    const computerSelection = computerPlay();
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You do not save what you are displaying with `Computer chose`, so the one you actually compare things to will likely be different than the one displayed, since it is random every time. Log `computerSelection` instead

Comment: all the if/else are fine ... the issue is, at the top of the code you run `computerPlay()` to output the computer choice, then later you run it again to determine a winner ... not often will the displayed choice equal the checked choice

Comment: @dnewbie25 your if/else statements are okay your log is the problem you are not checking the computer chose actually check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8xwkL3ey/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you must have already known, every time you call `computerPlay()`, computer chooses a random value.

When you call `computerPlay()` in below statement, you get a random selection.

```
console.log('Computer chose: ' + computerPlay()); // Random selection.
```

And when you call the function again later in the code as shown below, you get another random selection.

```
 const computerSelection = computerPlay(); // Random selection.
 console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

This is the reason the output you see is not consistent with the actual result.

**Solution:** Move above `console.log()` statement to execute after computer selection, and log the returned value, don't call `computerPlay()` again. If you call it again, you'll get another random selection, not the one you are passing to `playRound()` function.

```
const computerSelection = computerPlay();
console.log('Computer chose: ' + computerSelection);
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

**Working Example:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Rock Paper Scissors!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    //Computer's selection

    function computerPlay() {
      let selectRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
      if (selectRandom === 0) {
        return 'Rock';
      } else if (selectRandom === 1) {
        return 'Paper';
      } else {
        return 'Scissors';
      }
    }

    //Play round between human and computer
    function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {

      //Change to lowercase
      let player = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
      let computer = computerSelection.toLowerCase();


      //If player chooses rock
      if (player === 'rock') {
        if (computer === 'rock') {
          return 'It\'s a tie. Try again'
        } else if (computer === 'paper') {
          return 'You loose. Paper beats Rock'
        } else {
          return 'You win. Rock beats scissors'
        }

      }
      //If player chooses paper
      else if (player === 'paper') {
        if (computer === 'paper') {
          return 'It\'s a tie. Try again'
        }
        if (computer === 'scissors') {
          return 'You loose. Scissors beats Paper'
        } else {
          return 'You win. Paper beats Rock'
        }
      }

      //If player chooses scissors
      else {
        if (computer === 'scissors') {
          return 'It\'s a tie. Try again'
        } else if (computer === 'rock') {
          return 'You lose. Rock beats Scissors'
        } else {
          return 'You win. Scissors beats Paper'
        }
      }
    }

    const playerSelection = 'Paper';
    const computerSelection = computerPlay();
    console.log('Computer chose: ' + computerSelection);
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone! I didn't even notice that it was due to the first console.log('Computer chose: ' + computerPlay()). Now it works perfectly.